# How do extrinsic weights apply to Raspbery Pi full-nodes?

Tags: polkadot, weight, nodes

I'm running a `polkadot` full-node on a Raspberry Pi 4.

While the Substrate Fee system is determined by [Weights & Benchmarking](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/weights/calculate-fees/), how are different CPU architectures (when compared to the standard reference machine) treated under this economic model?

Comment: theoretically speaking, would it be possible to have different weights for different platforms, and then get the node to identify which platform it is under, then charge fees accordingly?

Comment: This doesn't make sense since blockchains must be deterministic and reach consensus, and thus a single amount of "weight" and "fee" must be chosen across the whole network, independent of whatever machine is running.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Weight system is not about block production, but actually about block import.

Remember that the high level story around weights is that we are trying to protect the network from blocks that are too large, and may take too long for the configured block time for that network.

Now protecting the network is absolutely not about protecting a single node from doing block production, but actually protecting **every** node on the network, all of which have to do block import.

So when the Polkadot network releases a suggested hardware specification, it is saying"

> You should expect to be able to import all blocks in less than or equal to 2 seconds on hardware which is at least as powerful as the recommended specification.

Now if you choose to run a full node on a Rasberry Pi, it may work while the network has a low number of transactions per block, but as blocks become more full, you should expect that your hardware will fall behind, and that you will never actually be able to catch up to the current block since it will take you longer per block to *import* than it will take validators to produce new blocks on the network.